# The requested script resource 'Compat.Timer.Timer.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Currently I upgraded my 3.5 web site to 4.0 for better performance I upgraded AjaxToolkit 3.5 to 4.0. And i'm found this error like :

> Server Error in '/EasyWeb' Application.
>
> The requested script resource 'Compat.Timer.Timer.js' requires version
>   'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use
>   this resource, make sure that the application references version
>   'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The requested
>   script resource 'Compat.Timer.Timer.js' requires version
>   'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use
>   this resource, make sure that the application references version
>   'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The requested script resource
>   'Compat.Timer.Timer.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit,
>   Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'
>   of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that
>   the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit,
>   Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.]
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager
>   scriptManager, Boolean zip) +469796
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager,
>   Boolean zip) +213
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1
>   uniqueScripts) +202    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()
>   +444    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +122
>   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +8872106
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2716 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

What I have to do to fix it now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an assembly version redirect to the AjaxToolkit reference in the web config:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="x.x.x.x-y.y.y.y" newVersion="z.z.z.z" />
```